# Android SDK not compiling apps correctly

Tags: java, android, debugging, nullpointerexception

It seems that the Android SDK doesn't compile my android app correctly. After building an app, I sometimes get seemingly random exceptions. The error goes away if I comment out the offending code, rebuild, uncomment the code, then rebuild again.

For instance, this code gave me a NullPointerException:

playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(settings, PLAY_GAME);
        }
        });

There is *nothing* wrong this code! Yet adb logcat tells me it's the cause of an exception.
Commenting out this code, rebuilding, uncommenting and rebuilding, makes the error go away.

What is going on?

This is making developing for android particularly frustrating.

**Update**: As I pointed out before, these are seemingly random errors that go away once I uncomment/recompile/comment/recompile. So I can't reproduce the stacktrace. It was a NullPointerException if I remember correctly.

However, if it is indeed buggy programming, why is the app running fine now w/o ANY errors at all?

Whenever I make a significant change to the app (add a new resource, a new class, function, etc), old code that was working fine breaks. Why?

**Update**: Seriously guys, lay off on the hate. I feel like a stumbled on a Atheists vs Christian debate. Sorry to have insunated that android was at fault. Started a new question with the latest errors:

[App Ran Fine, Now Breaking for Seemingly Unknown Reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547055/app-ran-fine-now-breaking-for-seemingly-unknown-reasons)

Comment: What is the exception that you get, when it happens? (It may be that the exception is actually thrown within the Activity, but reported in a way that (if you don't look closely) it seems like it's getting thrown from that line.

Comment: Are you sure playButton and settings are assigned correctly?  It seems WAY more likely that there's a bug in your code than the very widely used android toolkit for such a basic case.  Where are those variables declared and assigned?

Comment: Post your stacktrace showing the exception here, post more full code snippet. Android SDK is well built and tested tool which helped to build over 100K applications. So I doubt that problem is in SDK, that's more likely problem in your code. From what I see now I can conclude that sometimes playButton is null for some reason.

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. If you think there's something wrong with the Android SDK... prove it.

Comment: Re your update: Please show us how `playButton` is initialized and used. Also show us how the Intent (`settings`) is initialized, and how the Activity which handles it is initialized. Also, do you have _any_ AsyncTasks in your app?

Comment: I'm thinking that it's perhaps the emulator. Things start to crash as soon as it starts...and that's from a fresh install. Downloading the latest SDK and seeing if I still get the error

Comment: *"I'm thinking that it's perhaps the emulator."* - I'm thinking you'd have more luck sacrificing chickens at midnight.  Seriously, pay attention to what everyone is telling you ... and stop thinking up random reasons why it is not your code.

Comment: @Stephen C: I think it's pretty clear at this point that U Avalos is just trolling us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as noted in several other places, sometimes the source and the bin get out of sync. I've noticed numerous times, specially when making changes to XML. The solution, for commandline users, is to remove the bin directory, and re-compile. Problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

> Commenting out this code, rebuilding, uncommenting and rebuilding, makes the error go away.

This might seem to you like a bug in Android, but I suspect that the real problem is a threading / synchronization related bug in *your* code.  For instance, `playButton` may be being used before it is initialized.

But we cannot really help you unless you show us the stack trace and identify the line(s) of code where the exception was thrown.

---

> However, if it is indeed buggy programming, why is the app running fine now w/o ANY errors at all?

See above: it is most likely because you have a threading / synchronization issue.  You need to be aware that different parts of an application with a GUI will run in different threads ... even if you didn't explicitly create those threads.  There are rules you have to follow.  If you don't follow those rules, bad things happen ... like exceptions that sometimes happen and sometimes don't happen, depending on which way the wind is blowing.

Comment: playButton doesn't get used at all except in that code onCreate that's used to set up the setOnClickListener. If that's "standard" android behavior and not a bug, then that's truly counter-intuitive behavior. But like I said before that's just a sample of the random errors I get

Comment: @U Avalos: Perhaps you should withdraw the question until you get another exception with a stack trace. If it's as common as you seem to imply, then that shouldn't take long.

Comment: @Dan as a matter of fact, I'm getting a null pointer exception in another part of the code now

Comment: @U Avalos: Seriously, you're wasting your time and ours if you don't provide any tracebacks. If you don't know how to get a proper traceback, please ask for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your PLAY_GAME activity is returning without a result, e.g., if you press the back button & it just stops without calling setResult().